# How to get past `apparmor="DENIED" operation="open"`?

Tags: 20.04, apparmor, slack

I've upgraded `slack` (v4.27.154) via `snap` on 20.04 and `slack` no longer runs. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling to no avail. I've never messed with `apparmor` either.

After attempting to start slack, I see the following message in the Logs application.

```
audit: type=1400 audit(1656462082.516:35): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.slack.slack" name="/etc/slack.conf" pid=4493 comm="slack" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
```

This appears to be `apparmor`. So then I see the following:

```
$ sudo aa-status
[sudo] password for me: 
apparmor module is loaded.
25 profiles are loaded.
25 profiles are in enforce mode.
   /snap/core/13308/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine
   /snap/core/13308/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper
   /snap/snapd/15904/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine
   /snap/snapd/15904/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper
   /snap/snapd/16010/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine
   /snap/snapd/16010/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper
   docker-default
   snap-update-ns.core
   snap-update-ns.gnome-system-monitor
   snap-update-ns.mattermost-desktop
   snap-update-ns.slack
   snap-update-ns.snap-store
   snap-update-ns.teams-for-linux
   snap.core.hook.configure
   snap.gnome-system-monitor.gnome-system-monitor
   snap.gnome-system-monitor.hook.configure
   snap.mattermost-desktop.hook.configure
   snap.mattermost-desktop.mattermost-desktop
   snap.slack.hook.configure
   snap.slack.slack
   snap.snap-store.hook.configure
   snap.snap-store.snap-store
   snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software
   snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software-local-file
   snap.teams-for-linux.teams-for-linux
0 profiles are in complain mode.
6 processes have profiles defined.
6 processes are in enforce mode.
   /snap/slack/63/usr/lib/slack/slack (4493) snap.slack.slack
   /snap/slack/63/usr/lib/slack/slack (4497) snap.slack.slack
   /snap/slack/63/usr/lib/slack/slack (4498) snap.slack.slack
   /snap/slack/63/usr/lib/slack/slack (4605) snap.slack.slack
   /snap/slack/63/usr/lib/slack/slack (4615) snap.slack.slack
   /snap/snap-store/558/usr/bin/snap-store (3668) snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software
0 processes are in complain mode.
0 processes are unconfined but have a profile defined.
```

After searching for the `snap.slack.slack` file (thinking I can add it to the disable directory), I find only the following files:

```
/sys/fs/cgroup/devices/snap.slack.slack
/var/cache/apparmor/26b63962.0/snap.slack.slack
/var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap.slack.slack
```

But there are no files in `/etc/apparmor.d` for `snap.slack.slack`.

Anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem with same slack and Ubuntu version.

For the moment I've made a snap revert slack to go back to version 4.26.1 and slack is working again.

I have made a comparison between old and new /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap.slack.slack profiles and it is the same (except SNAP_REVISION).

I can't find any mention of /etc/slack.conf access into snap.slack.slack profile.

I have a slack.conf file in /etc/ but it is related to an other slack application :  [slack - Sysadmin's lazy autoconfiguration kit](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/slack.8.html)

Comment: So, you're saying you just changed `SNAP_REVISION` in `/var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap.slack.slack`? What did you change that to? I have `63` currently. I was unable to use snap to rollback because I think I had already removed Slack when trying to reinstall.

Comment: I too see no mention of `slack.conf` in the `snap.slack.slack` profiles, but apparmor is failing on a read of `/etc/slack.conf`.

Comment: I didn't change SNAP_REVISION on profiles. I made the comparison before and after updating and the only change is SNAP_REVISION.

Comment: I think there is a change in Slack (wrong path ?) ... that is causing this bug ... but as Slack is not open source. And I can't find any support page on Slack website.